# Remote Help Program Help

Tags: 14.04

I just switched to linux last week, me being a total noob often ask my friends for help. On windows I would just send them a join.me link but join.me does not work with ubuntu. Does anyone have a good, simple method to remote connect (from an external address) if there is a function inside ubuntu that would be great, otherwise i program will do just fine!

Comment: [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en) works in Ubuntu. It has a share your desktop option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the stock Desktop Sharing App, for which you need a VNC Client from https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/ .

The VNC viewer is also available as a Chrome App, and is a handy little feature.

But, the major problem is that one needs to know about firewall settings, and of course port forwarding.

So, the other alternative is TeamViewer, which is often used by many people. You can use it for linux, but also, don't forget to install `wine`

Also, though I haven't tested, install `wine` and then install join.me in `wine`

If you don't know `wine` is an Windows emulator program.

Answer (score 1):

Open the the sharing settings app and switch on desktop sharing, then others can connect using any vnc client.